# How to stop UIDynamicAnimator in applicationDidEnterBackground

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios7, ios6

How can I stop a `UIDynamicAnimator` when `applicationDidEnterBackground` is called? Also, how can I start the timer in `applicationWillEnterForeground`? Here's the code I have:

in my **game viewcontroller.m**

```
 -(void)stoptime
{
     [_animator removeAllBehaviors]; //_animator is my UIDynamicAnimator
      [time invalidate];
}
```

in my **app delegate.m**

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
       gameViewController *new=[[gameViewController   alloc]initWithNibName:@"gameViewController" bundle:nil];
    [new stoptime];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `NSNotificationCenter`. In your view controller, listen for notifications (in `viewDidLoad`):

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(stoptime) name:@"StopTimeNotification" object:nil];
```

Then, in your `applicationDidEnterBackground:`

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"StopTimeNotification" object:nil];
}
```

Finally, in your `stoptime` method:

```
-(void)stoptime {

    [_animator removeAllBehaviors]; //_animator is my UIDynamicAnimator
    [time invalidate];
    time = nil;
}
```

Be sure to call the following when your view controller is about to be freed:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
```

Two additional comments:

1 - When invalidating a timer, it's good practice to set it to `nil` as well so you can reuse it later

2 - Don't use `new` as a name for any variable, it's a reserved keyword.

**EDIT**

You can use a similar method for restarting your timer.